# Secure password management on local SQLite database

Tags: python, security, encryption, sqlite

What is the 'proper' way to store passwords locally on a machine for a single user application?

I am writing myself a password manager, so I am unable to store the hash of the password (as I physically want to retrieve it).

I am using an SQLite database with python, which stores the username, the password, and the IV used for encryption (all encrypted with the password manager applications master key which is not stored anywhere, and is provided by the user), but what is the proper procedure for protecting the database?

Currently the application has a master password the user must set up, but how do I check to see if this password is right before attempting to decrypt the database (potentially breaking it if wrong) without storing it somewhere?

Is the bottom line I must store a salted and hashed master password somewhere on disk?

Comment: since the passwords are encrypted, there is no need in securing the database.

Comment: Are the contents of the DB useful for an attacker that does not know the master key? Anyway, the master PW must be hashed+salted (or better, use a more complex KDF), but then could be stored inside the DB.

Comment: _"how do I check to see if this password is right before attempting to decrypt the database"_ - you don't, you attempt to decrypt with it, and if it succeeds, you know that it was the right password.